# About the definition of generalized harmonic numbers and an identity

Tags: approximation, riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers, dirichlet-series

Some software packages make use of the following definition for generalized harmonic numbers. In what follows, $\sigma,t\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$H_{ t }^{(\sigma+it)}=\zeta (\sigma+it)-\zeta \
(\sigma+it, t  +1)$$

where $\zeta(x)$ is the Riemann zeta function and $\zeta(x,y)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function. Also, some of these packages use the following default evaluation:

$$\sum _ {m=1}^{\lfloor t \rfloor} \
\frac{1}{m^{\sigma+it}}=H_{\lfloor t \rfloor }^{(\sigma+it)}=\zeta (\sigma+it)-\zeta \
(\sigma+it, \lfloor t \rfloor  +1)$$

My question is whether this last identity above is a known and proven identity; in other words, is the sum really exactly and provably equal to the rightmost expression in terms of the Riemann zeta and the Hurwitz zeta

Comment: @StevenClark. Yes, thank you, that was a typo. I have edited the question.

Comment: IMHO, the first one is wrong and the second correct. Where did you see the first one written ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Both Maple and Mathematica appear to do this, and maybe other packages. You can look up the Maple documentation by googling “generalized harmonic numbers in maple” and clicking on the top hit. In the case of Mathematica, you can see this by using FunctionExpand[HarmonicNumber[t,sigma+I t]]. HarmonicNumber in Mathematica is incorrectly documented; this is a bug that the developers are now aware of and will get corrected. But now, you claim the the second equation in the post is actually correct? Would you have a reference for a proof, or could you show a proof?